# Masstransit use Queues instead of topics for each endpoint in Azure Service Bus

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

is there a way to force masstransit to use Queues instead of topics in Azure Service Bus ? I want to limit myself to the free tier of azure service bus and this limits me to use only queues and not topics. But mass transit by default creates a topic for each receiver endpoint. Does someone know a way to accomplish that Please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use MassTransit with the basic tier by:

Calling `SelectBasicTier` on each receive endpoint.

Set `ConfigureConsumeTopology = false` on every receive endpoint.

Set `PublishFaults = false` on every receive endpoint.

Only use `Send`, never `Publish`, to send messages to queues.

That should prevent the creations of any topics or setting message properties to invalid values. Though I honestly haven't tried it in, well, years, so there may be some other aspect that calls into the topology that isn't supported.